# How to properly setState to array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array ob objects that creates `Close` buttons depending on how many there are of them. When i click `Close` button i would expect the array to be updated (removed) then the button element will disappear from screen.

I have worked out in `console.log` but unable to properly do setState :(

Example code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-kilby-hn2d9

Any help would be greatly appreciated, i believe it's just the formatting of setState i need to do it properly, but because its array of an objects and so on i just cant figure that one out.

Comment: Please put your code in your question, not linked to an external site.

Comment: Or if you want to [add an item to the state](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26253351/1218980).

Comment: Emile i tried but failing, i think I'm just writing setState incorrectly.

Answer (score -1):

Here is your handleclick function rewritten, you forgot to return the state at the end after modifying it according to your needs :

```
  handleClick = i => {
    this.setState(state => {
      var newState = {allProjects: []};
      for (let z = 0; z < state.allProjects.length; z++) {
        const element = state.allProjects[z].employees;
        const items = element.filter(item => item !== i);
        console.log('filter', items);
        console.log('===========');
        newState.allProjects[z] = Object.assign({}, state.allProjects[z]);
        newState.allProjects[z].employees = items;
      }
      return newState;
    });
  };
```

Comment: This mutates the current state, which is forbidden in React.

Comment: You should try it yourself by removing the "return state;" at the end and realize that it does not mutates the current state, otherwise the return statement wouldn't be required for it to work. Or am I wrong ?

Comment: `state.allProjects[z].employees = items` mutates the `state` reference you're using.

Comment: oh, indeed, I make the correction.

Comment: Emile, is it ok now ?